# how can i put a default value in a field and this field is in a tree

Tags: odoo-16

```
<record id="view_mahmoud_product_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">mahmoud.product.form</field>
            <field name="model">mahmoud.product</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Product">
                    <group>
                    Products:<field name="name"/>
                    </group>
                    <br> </br>
                    Category:<field name="category_product"/>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record id="view_mahmoud_product" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">mahmoud.product.tree</field>
            <field name="model">mahmoud.product</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree>
                    <field name="name"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record id="action_product" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Product Platform</field>
            <field name="res_model">mahmoud.product</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="o_view_nocontent._smiling_face">Create your first product!</p>
            </field>
        </record>
```

in the field name in the tree section I want a default value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fki4K.png)

I tried everything but nothing worked